# Glade, GtkBuiler or Gtk unexpectedly swapped a signal handler

Tags: c, gtk, signals

```
void
add_button_clicked(GtkButton * widget, GtkTreeView * treeview){
    printf("%s\n",G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(widget));
}   // Prints GtkTreeView
```

While the standard GtkButton:clicked signal is supposed to work like this (the widget itself followed by the user data) for some reason, the swapped signal handler has been called here and the two parameters are mixed up.

I could just shuffle the code around a bit to get past this but I would like to get to the bottom of *why* this is happening so I can fix/prevent it.

The glade swap checkbox is unchecked, and I didn't manually connect the signal anywhere, so I don't know why this is happening.

**Edit:** Ok, now it's happening to ALL my callbacks which is a big huge tremendous problem! Please help!

**Edit:** This "Feature" is apparently here so glade users can add a glade object to the callback and directly reference a gtk function so that they can for example hide a widget without having to write a single line of code. I'll roll with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glade does this so that when you pass another object you can call a standard gtk function directly on it (Such as closing a window) without needing to write any code at all.